# How to turn off autofix space in HTML tailwind?

Tags: css, tailwind-css, tailwind-ui, tailwind-3

There is a utility class in tailwind:

```
  @apply block w-full bg-gray input-color-gray input-color-gray font-roboto-100 rounded-md sm: text-sm p-3 bg-gray pr-4;
```

Problem is when I save a document it formats inline style with space:

```
sm: text-sm
```

It should be witout space: `sm:text-sm`.

How to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

you can disable the formatter in software like vs code

you can also find other formatters that are less vigorous

what are you using to edit the code?